# How to show `&amp;` in a label control in aspx page

Tags: c#, escaping, ampersand

How can I show the text `"Replace & with &amp;"` in label or textbox in aspx page? When I put `Text="Replace & with &amp;"` in aspx page, I get output as "Replace & with &"

Comment: Text="Replace &amp; with &amp;amp;"  or HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("&amp;"); What is the best practice?

Answer (score 3):

Use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("&amp;")`; this is always working and the resulting code is more readable.

Comment: I agree with you Felice. This also goes in codebehind and not in aspx. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `&` with `&amp;`:

```
Text = "Replace &amp; with &amp;amp;";
```

You could also make it work for any character, not just `&`:

```
string s = "<";
Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Replace " + s +
                              " with " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s));
```

Comment: It didn't work on aspx page but worked in the codebehind. Why?